# Reduce a web site loading time in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I created a site in wordpress. Site contains so many long pages, and many java scripts. But after a completion of site, server get so many loading time so that what change should be need  to reduce a loading time ?

Comment: Reduce some of the javascript and js that are non of use and remove those js that are conflicting...

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions

- Use CloudFlare or Use Google mod_pagespeed UI
- Use [W3 Total Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) or [WP super cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/)
- Try gzip/http compression your site from w3 total cache
- Use db cache reloaded fix
- Use [Smush-it](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smushit/)/[Ewww Image Optimizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ewww-image-optimizer/) to decrease image site

You can visit also below sites :

http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/5-quick-ways-to-speed-up-your-wordpress-site/
http://www.sparringmind.com/speed-up-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

- Use `wp_enqueue_script` to avoid multiple `j`s `jQuery` `css` files being called. I mean there are many plugins referring to different versions of jQuery them use `wp_enqueue_script`.
- Try installing `W3 Total Cache` plugin where you can optimize your site, minimize css and combine jQuery files.
- Try loading your site @ whichloadsfaster.com. Analyze the results and work accordingly. Hope this would suffice.
- For faster loading try optimizing your code, ask yourself whether each plugin that you have installed is worth keeping, remove them if not needed.
  Also try configuring a CDN for your blog, this will surely reduce loading time as well as load on your server.

Answer (score 0):

- Use CloudFlare or Use Google mod_pagespeed UI
- Use W3 Total Cache or WP super cahe
- Try gzip/http compression your site from w3 total cache
- Use db cache reloaded fix
- Use Smush-it/Ewww Image Optimizer to decrease image site

Answer (score 0):

- As the mentioned here above, use a CDN like Amazon Cloudfront or Cloudflare.
- Use Amazon S3 for store all your medias like images and so.
- Try to load all your Javascripts at the bottom of your body-end-tag.

Thats my best tips, that will reduce much.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using W3Total Cache, make sure to use file renaming or query strings to bust cache when pushing updated files:

http://robandlauren.com/2013/04/11/busting-cache-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you look into using W3 Total Cache. Like others have stated, you can minify and cache several of your pages. W3TC also has CDN support. If you'd like to go the easy route, check out its integration with MaxCDN, otherwise I recommend Amazon CloudFront.

Additionally you may want to see if CloudFlare is for you.

Out of the box WordPress is very fast. It only starts to slow down through your choice of plugins and themes. Go through them and delete anything that's unnecessary. Yes, delete even deactivated plugins/themes.

WP Smush.it has been taken over by WPMU and has improved immensely. Definitely recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using W3 Total Cache try disabling (if you've turned on) the "Object Cache" feature. I've fixed a lot of problem with site loading disabling this feature and disabling che "Live traffic" on Wordfence